# Hosting multiple websites, but not in same public folder structure

Tags: web-hosting, multiple-domains

Is there any good popular hosts that allows under a single account, multiple web sites to be hosted in independent folder structures?

At the moment I'm using webzpro.com. And I'm forced to have one base domain, and then other pages as addon domains. This means that one web site can be accessed through the address of my other website, if a user for some reason would find out the directory name.

So for example GoDaddy, Bluehost, etc, do they all function the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't standard, just a decision made by some hosts. It doesn't inherently require a reseller plan. Some that don't:

- WebFaction
- MediaTemple's grid service
- Dreamhost(not recommending, just stating a fact)

Answer (score 3):

On most LAMP shared hosts you can get this feature by purchasing reseller hosting rather than the standard shared hosting. You typically use a tool called WHM to manage the multiple domain (or a custom in-house tool) and each domain account has it's own login and file structure. They also have separate file and bandwidth levels that you'll have to monitor.